# PHP Manual: Number Conversion in Is_Numeric Example 1?

Tags: php, evaluation, isnumeric

I ran across this example in the PHP documentation:

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "42",
    1337,
    0x539,
    02471,
    0b10100111001,
    1337e0,
    "not numeric",
    array(),
    9.1
);

foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo "'{$element}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
'42' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'1337' is numeric
'not numeric' is NOT numeric
'Array' is NOT numeric
'9.1' is numeric
```

The five examples after '42' all evaluate to '1337'. I can understand why this is the case for '1337e0' (scientific notation), but I don't understand why that is the case for the rest of them.

I wasn't able to find anyone mentioning it in the comments of the documentation and I haven't found it asked here, so could anyone explain why '0x539', '02471', and '0b10100111001' all evaluate to '1337'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When outputting all numbers get converted to normal representation. Which is decimal number system, and non-scientific notation (e.g. `1e10` - scientific float).

Hex:

*Hex numbers start with `0x` and are followed by any of `0-9a-f`.*

```
0x539 = 9*16^0 + 3*16^1 + 5*16^2 = 1337
```

Octal:

*Octal numbers start with a `0` and contain only the integers 0-7.*

```
02471 = 1*8^0 + 7*8^1 + 4*8^2 + 2*8^3 = 1337
```

Binary:

*Binary numbers start `0b` and contain `0`s and/or `1`s.*

```
0b10100111001 = 1*2^0 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^8 + 1*2^10 = 1337
```

Answer (score 2):

They are octal, hexadecimal and binary numbers.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php